# Multiple Uploads to delete individually in Formidable Forms

Tags: wordpress, file-upload, formidable

I have a custom plugin made that interacts with Formidable Forms, in order to run some price calculations on the number of words inside an uploaded document. But this was unfortunately suited for one upload at a time. Someone is trying to make multiple uploads possible for me, but we are running into a problem:

Using the multiple upload option, all files turn up in a list, where I'd like them to be seperately listed with a delete option.

Does anyone know if this is possible? And how? If I can help by posting code here, please ask!